# Capture onClick of a Codemirror textbox

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'd need a little help with Codemirror. What I'd like to do is when I click into a textbox, I want to get its ID.

With a pure HTML textbox it works, I can get the ID of the textarea. See code here: http://jsfiddle.net/aWAQY/

```
<form name="x" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
<textarea id="testextarea" name="testextarea" onClick="getname();"></textarea>
</form>
<script>
function getname() {
var tname = document.getElementById('testextarea').name;
alert(tname);
}
</script>
```

But if I call the getname() function on a CodeMirror textbox via onClick, nothing happens. Actually not even an onClick="alert('hello world');" pops up.

Is there any other, specific way how I can get the ID of a CM textarea and/or make onClick work?

Thanks!

Comment: You should describe your original problem, instead of the possible solution.

Comment: The original problem is that the possible solution doesn't work. :) In pure HTML the JS code works but not with a CodeMirror textarea instance, this is the problem. I'm not sure why the same JS code why doesn't work with CM.

Comment: one probable cause is, that your inline event handler (that one defined using the attribute `onclick=""`) is overridden through the loading code of CodeMirror. Here you have a perfect example why must not use inline JS at all. Set up your own click handler using `addEventListener()` which can add multiple event handler. See the JSFiddle link in my answer below for a working example without inline JS.

Comment: What are you registering the click handler on? CodeMirror will hide the textarea it is acting on, and replace it with a new set of DOM nodes. Thus, click handlers on the texarea won't be present on the new editor interface.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, found it: this needs a CM onmouse event. http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events

No need for onClick, just need to add to the CM instance:

```
 instance.on("mousedown", function(instance, e) {
   var tname = document.getElementById('testextarea').id;
   alert(tname);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this i think this will work.**

```
<form name="x" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
<textarea id="testextarea" name="testextarea" onClick="getname(this.id);"></textarea>
</form>
<script>
function getname(id) {
alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about CodeMirror, but that code you got there should work and I wouldn't bother about bugs in CodeMirror.

You can also refer to the event target to get the name inside the event handler:

```
function( event ) {
    var tname = event.target.name;
    alert( tname );
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/aWAQY/1/ for an example without inline JS.

Or the updated version, using two event handler on the dame textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/aWAQY/2/